# The SessionStateTempDataProvider requires SessionState to be enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc

HI i am getting error : "The SessionStateTempDataProvider requires SessionState to be enabled."
when i try to handle the error.
i got a piece of code from the blog below.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shay/archive/2009/03/06/real-world-error-hadnling-in-asp-net-mvc-rc2.aspx
i am not using any session. my session state is set to off in web.config.

and from the below thread
[The SessionStateTempDataProvider requires SessionState to be enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720367/the-sessionstatetempdataprovider-requires-sessionstate-to-be-enabled)
i got a solution to set the 
but its already set as such.
how  to avoid the error. i dont want to use session.

Comment: Code. We need to see the code that causes the error.

Comment: The code that i am using is from this blog.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shay/archive/2009/03/06/real-world-error-hadnling-in-asp-net-mvc-rc2.aspx

Comment: The sample project attached to that blog post worked fine for me. Did you change anything with that project?

Comment: no.. i didnt download the sample projet in the blog.
what i did is that i just copied an paste the contents from the blog.
Application_Error method and i have created ErrorController.cs and pasted the respective codes.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884852/how-can-i-disable-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

> my session state is set to off in web.config.

That should be what's causing the problem. Apparently, ASP.NET MVC needs the session state.

Check this question about [disabling session state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884852/how-can-i-disable-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: sorry for my statement, "my session state is set to off in web.config"
i am not setting <sessionState mode="Off" /> in my web.config.
i tried searching the text, but couldnt find it.

Comment: @Nimesh, it must have something to do with the SessionState being disabled. Because that's the only way I am able to reproduce the error. Plus, that's what the error message suggests.

Comment: yeah i agree to your point. but i am not able to extract that out.
is there any other ways to handle errors?

Comment: Of course. The base controller has a virtual method called `HandleUnknownAction`. You can have your own base controller, derived from the `Controller` class and handle 404 errors there. You can also have your own `HandleError` attribute to hande errors occured on controllers/actions. Example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766610/how-to-get-elmah-to-work-with-asp-net-mvc-handleerror-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code out:

https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/master/src/NuGetGallery/Infrastructure/CookieTempDataProvider.cs

It acts just like default `TempDataProvider` but instead it uses cookies. If you are not carrying sensitive data with TempData, it might help.