# SessionStateTempDataProvider class requires session state to be enabled Umbraco Contour

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco5, umbraco-contour

When I tried to add Contour form inside RTE, I am getting this error in 7.2.4,

> The SessionStateTempDataProvider class requires session state to be enabled

on following line of code in MvcRenderContourForm.cshtml present in macroScripts folder:

```
@Html.RenderMvcAction(action, controller, formGuid, formtoken, (umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNode)Model, (System.Dynamic.DynamicObject)Parameter);
```

Its like a dead end for me now, please help.

Comment: Are you sure it is umbraco related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720367/the-sessionstatetempdataprovider-requires-sessionstate-to-be-enabled

Comment: I can't find any related issues on the umbraco bugtracker (http://issues.umbraco.org/issues/U4?q=SessionStateTempDataProvider).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add macro inside template and it will work :)

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/47723-Unable-to-render-form-in-richtext-editor-30180-(Umbraco-7)?p=3#comment215341